# How to configure django app (Heroku) as subdomain of static portfolio site (Dreamhost)

Tags: python, django, heroku, web, host

I have a simple portfolio website with some html and css files in the root directory of the site hosted by Dreamhost. I also have a Django app that I'd like to place in a subdomain of this same website. However, Heroku will be serving the django app. I'm confused about how to organize and configure the whole portfolio/django website. How would the system work using two different hosts? Should I integrate the static portfolio site into the django project? Or do I keep them completely seperate and have them live on their own servers? Sorry if my question doesn't make sense. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the internet's concerned, a subdomain is a completely separate website. You can point a subdomain at whatever address you like; the internet doesn't care that it's a completely separate host. You can host your system however you like: both on Dreamhost, both on Heroku, or one on each. The latter setup is the most complex, so we'll walk through that one here.

Let's say your site is `example.com` and you want the portfolio site to be `portfolio.example.com`. If your app's running on Heroku, it'll have a name similar to `yourportfolio.herokuapp.com`. So we need to do two things: tell Heroku that your app is served from `portfolio.example.com`, and tell the DNS system to point from your subdomain from Heroku.

#### Pointing the subdomain to Heroku

Presuming your domain name is hosted on Dreamhost, go to the **Domains** section of the control panel, then **Manage Domains**. Under `example.com` is a link called **DNS**. You need to add a custom `CNAME` record; set *name* to `portfolio`, *type* to `CNAME`, and *value* to `yourportfolio.herokuapp.com.`.  `CNAME`s are a way of setting up aliases on the web; they mean "this site is also known as *foo*".

#### Telling Heroku to serve your app

Within your Heroku project, run `heroku domains:add portfolio.example.com`.

[Heroku has documentation about subdomains here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains), which is a useful overview of the process as well as giving details of more complex setups.